# reactjs, const, passing properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and taking over a piece of emergency work. I have a component which is invoked on the index page and I am trying to push an object property into it.

---

so there are two methods here of doing this

```
const TestBundle = ({lang}) => (
  <section className='relative-container'>
    <div className='row'>
        {lang}
    </div>
  </section>
)

TestBundle .propTypes = {
  lang: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

^ this works.. but how do I get this next concept to work properly - when I tried this solution I had all sort of errors.

```
const TestBundle = (props) => {
    const lang = props.lang

      <section className='relative-container'>
        <div className='row'>
            {lang}
        </div>
      </section>
}
```

//different example

```
const TestBundle = (props) => {
    const lang = props.lang

      <section className='relative-container'>
        <div className='row'>
            {lang}
        </div>
      </section>
}

export default TestBundle
```

-- but this comes up with the error

```
./src/components/Services/TestBundle.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: D:/wamp/www/project/react/src/components/Services/TestBundle.js: Unexpected token (5:2)

  3 | 
  4 | const TestBundle= (props) => {
> 5 |   const lang = props.lang
    |   ^
  6 |   
  7 |   <section className='relative-container'>
  8 |
```

Comment: You can't put JSX in a middle of a block!

Comment: `return <section ....;`

Comment: Please demonstrate with some answers. @Felix Kling - you just propose smacking a return at the top of section?

Comment: Yes. The function needs to return something.

Comment: yeah was checking on the syntax -- now what is the difference between these two methods - whats the best one to use -- why is it ok one way - the other way needs a return - you said JSX - what's the indicator of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple fix; you need to add a return statement for your JSX. As it stands you're not returning anything and you are mixing JSX with your constant definition:

```
const TestBundle = (props) => {
  const lang = props.lang;
  return (
    <section className='relative-container'>
      <div className='row'>
        {lang}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Or, if you prefer a slightly shorter syntax:

```
const TestBundle = (props) => <section className='relative-container'>
    <div className='row'>
      {props.lang}
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: now what is the difference between these two methods - whats the best one to use -- why is it ok one way - the other way needs a return - you said JSX - what's the indicator of this

Comment: @TheOldCounty, what do you mean? The one is shorter in syntax because rather than first declaring a constant and then using it, I use the value directly. i.e the first is like doing `x=y+1` and then using `x` whereas the last is using `y+1` directly. It's only a matter of preference. If a functional component **only returns** and doesn't do any logic, then you can omit the `return`. Otherwise you have to do like in the first example. As for what JSX is, please have a look [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/introducing-jsx.html).

Comment: I was going back to my question -- "const TestBundle = ({lang}) => ("  and "const TestBundle = (props) => {"

Comment: @TheOldCounty That's called "deconstructing". Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: I've never had to do that -- normally just loop through the data -- but what I mean is -- these two methods - which is more appropriate to use -- so I'd say the props version because I can pass more than one parameter. But also why is the syntax different etc..

Comment: @TheOldCounty, I suggest you post a new question because this is getting off-topic and there's not enough room too explain in the comment section.

Comment: I do have another question.. about reducers and language switching